# Why refer to Near Infrared Reflectance Spectroscopy (NIRS) while using a much wider spectrum (350-2500 nm)?

Tags: conventions, computational-physics, spectroscopy, wavelength

I am puzzled about the way a method names vs. specificity of the method differ in the literature around spectroscopy applications.

A very widely used field spectroradiometer, recording reflectance spectrum from $350$ nm to $2500$ nm, is reported in the Material and Methods of plethora of papers, from medical to agricultural studies.

Oftentimes, the wavelength range is described ($350 - 2500$ nm), together with a title along the lines of "Near infrared spectroscopy gives new insights in the field of X" and extensively referring to NIRS as a method.

However, the spectrum range encompasses more than Near Infrared Reflectance ($700 - 2500$ nm) since visible light ($350 - 700$ nm) is typically also included in the analyses.

1. I don't understand why one would call a method NIRS if using more than NIR.
2. I am still struggling to see if this is a convention, a incorrect naming from the authors, or a misunderstanding from my part.

I am not an expert in this field and also use spectroscopy essentially for prediction of physical and chemical properties. In brief I am asking: should one refer to a method as reflectance spectroscopy, near-infrared spectroscopy or anything else, if using the full range of wavelength available in spectroscopy analyses?